# Get the actual Javascript Error object with window.onerror

Tags: javascript, error-handling, onerror

Javascript has this great callback `window.onerror`. It's quite convenient to track any error. However, it calls with the error name, the file name and the line. It's certainly not as rich as getting the actual error object from a `try...catch` statement. 
The actual error object contains a lot more data, so I am trying to get that. Unfortunately, `try...catch` statement do not work fine when you start having async code.

Is there a way to combine and get the best of both worlds? I initially looked for a way to get  the *last* error triggered within an `onerror` block, but it looks like JS doesn't store that.

Any clue?

Comment: to catch error override the functions like setTimeout and setInveral and put a try catch loop inside them. You will be able to catch all the errors. Make sense ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're referring to stack trace of the error object, then AFAIK, this is not possible.

Simple reason being that a stack trace is related to an execution context in which runtime exceptions (handled with try...catch...finally) were created or thrown (with `new Error()` or `throw`).

Whereas when `window.onerror` is invoked, it is called within a different context.

You can get some mileage by inspecting `window.event` (not available on FF) in your `onerror` handler.

Comment: Dang. The stack trace is actually one of the things I am looking for :/ Not sure I understand why this couldn't be "persisted" in some way, as it's an array of strings though...

Comment: Its not persisted because the scope in which it was created is no longer there. In case of try/catch, you still are in _that_ scope.

Comment: Take a look at this:http://helephant.com/2007/05/12/diy-javascript-stack-trace/ May be helpful in your case, not sure though.

Comment: @Mrchief that's incorrect, at least in Chrome. Stacktraces are available even when their enclosing scope is "finished". To illustrate: `try { throw new Error("err!"); } catch(e) { window.the_error = e; }; console.log(window.the_error.stack);`

Comment: @gfxmonk: So you're saying my 1.5 year old answer is incorrect because of a proprietary thing that Chrome did in their recent versions? Is what chrome doing part of any spec? If not, my answer is still good.

Comment: @Mrchief It's not just chrome (firefox too), and I doubt it's that recent. Your answer to the question is correct, but your reasoning is not valid - for every browser (that I've checked) where errors have a `stack` property, it's maintained regardless of the execution context. Whether your statement used to be correct or not, it's still worth correcting.

Comment: @gfxmonk: `window.the_error` is not a standard property. Browsers may create such properties (firefox just follows webkit) for obvious reasons, but its important to note that its not the JS engine rather the browser maintaining them. As far as the OPs requirement goes, I guess `window.the_error` may fulfill that (obviously may not work across browsers), although I never played with it so I'm not sure what it does and what are its quirks. My reasoning is based on how JS execution happens, browsers plugging in their own stuff has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Mrchief He's assigning the trapped error to `window.the_error`.  there's no special property involved.  It's just illustrating that an `Error` object retains its stack trace, even when its execution context has gone away.

Comment: @Nevir: I understand that. But its not the `Error` object that is retained. You're creating a variable and holding on to it in the global (window) scope. They are just like any other global variables. This is intrusive and requires you to wrap every thing inside a `try...catch`. What OP asked was to get the last error details without having to resort to such manual hacks.

Answer (score 51):

this is now possible in some browsers.
The [spec](http://html5.org/tools/web-apps-tracker?from=8085&to=8086) was updated to include the actual error with stacktrace as the 5th parameter.

the problem is that not every browser supports this yet, so you could do something like this:

```
window.onerror = function(message, filename, lineno, colno, error)
{
    if(error != null)
    {
        //handle the error with stacktrace in error.stack
    }
    else
    {
        //sadly only 'message', 'filename' and 'lineno' work here
    }
};
```

Comment: would there be a nice way to pass this error to an angular.js service that is contained in a ng-app?

Comment: works at least on Chrome, IE11, and Firefox >=31. I haven't tested Safari and mobile versions yet. Seems to be quite well supported now.

Comment: @user2151819 great news

Answer (score 7):

Modern browsers fully support the HTML 5 draft spec for [ErrorEvent](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#the-errorevent-interface) and `window.onerror`. In both of these browsers you can either use window.onerror, or (amazingly!) bind to the 'error' event properly:

```
// Only Chrome & Opera pass the error object.
window.onerror = function (message, file, line, col, error) {
    console.log(message, "from", error.stack);
};
// Only Chrome & Opera have an error attribute on the event.
window.addEventListener("error", function (e) {
    console.log(e.error.message, "from", e.error.stack);
});
```

Comment: What is the syntac if I want to name a function?... window.onerror = MyErrorFunction