# data:URI incompatible with window.onerror

Tags: javascript, data-uri

When generating content via `data:URI`, I've noticed that Javascript errors are reported as "script error" by the page's `window.onerror` handler. However, Firefox's Error Console lists the exact errors.

For example:

```
<script>
var HTML = "<script>window.onerror = function(msg){alert(msg)}<\/script>";
HTML    += "<script> var str ='hello world;<\/script>";

window.open("data:text/html;base64," + window.btoa(HTML));
</script>
```

When run, a popup window displays "script error", whereas Firefox's error console states "unterminated string literal".

Is there a way to have the exact error reported via `window.onerror`?

This is for in-house debugging, so cross-browser compatibility is not a requirement.

Thanks!

Comment: If it is for in-house debugging only you can properly unset some of FF security features in your prefs.js

Comment: @powtac I've tried unsetting `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` but I still only get "script error" in FF 3.6. Which other policies should I disable?

Comment: You should open a second question for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the actual Javascript Error object with window.onerror](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099127/get-the-actual-javascript-error-object-with-window-onerror)