# Webpack and Capturing Error Events

Tags: javascript, error-handling, webpack, exception

I am trying to get the original error on the error event listener. However, when the listener is attached from a different script I get the generic "script error" with no stack trace. My understanding is this occurs for cross-origin scripts. However, all of my scripts live inside of the app bundle created by Webpack.

**Example**

`app.js`

```
window.addEventListener("error", function (errEvt) {
    console.log(errEvt, window.myErr);
});
```

`some-file.js`

```
function generateError() {
    let foo = {};

    try {
        foo.bar();
    } catch (err) {
        window.myErr = err;
        throw new Error(err);
    }
}
```

These both get bundled into `app.bundle.js`.

```
<script src="app/app.bundle.js"></script>
```

If I attach the error generator to a document click event then I get the following.

```
(app.js context) window.myErr --> TypeError: foo.bar is not a function
at errors (eval at <anonymous> (app.bundle.js:45), <anonymous>:37:13)

(app.js context) errEvt --> ErrorEvent {message: "Script error.", filename: "", lineno: 0, colno: 0…}
```

What's going on? Shouldn't these scripts then be considered same origin (they all "live" in `app.bundle.js`? Is there any way to get the original error without resorting to manually binding it to the window object in a `try / catch`?

**References**

https://blog.sentry.io/2016/05/17/what-is-script-error.html

[Get the actual Javascript Error object with window.onerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099127/get-the-actual-javascript-error-object-with-window-onerror)

Comment: I have the exact same issue - there is a JS error somewhere inside webpack bundle and I can't trace it with external error handler, I only get a generic 'script error'.