# How to capture unhandledrejection events from a webpack chunk (in Vue)?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I am using Vue and want to be informed if and error occurs on client side. Therefore I have added an event handler in my main app: App.vue

```
created() {
    const APP = this;
    window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function (event) {
        APP.sendError("uncaught (in promise) " + event.reason);
    });
},
```

Using vue-router I have got some pages like this:

```
  {
    path: "/register",
    name: "register",
    meta: { requiresAuth: false, layout: simpleLayout }, 
    component: () =>
      import(
        /* webpackChunkName: "register" */ "xso-common/src/login/register"
      ),
  },
```

The /* webpackChunkName: "register" */ will create a register.js file next to the app.js file.

The unhandledrejection should get fired if a Promise gets rejected and is not catched.

While developing this works fine, but if its build for production the unhandledrejection event gets not fired if an error Promise gets rejected in another file than app.js.

So if the Promise gets rejected in app.js it works.

But if the Promise gets rejected in register.js the unhandledrejection is not fired.

I have searched a lot and some sites claims that it occurs if the .js file is from another origin, but it this is not the case. The js sources comes from the same domain.

I noticed someone has asked something similaire 5 years ago, with no responses:
[Webpack and Capturing Error Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122902/webpack-and-capturing-error-events)

Does anyone have got an idea how to fix this these days?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to move a listener to main entry point? It should be set as soon as possible. The problem is that router navigation (and so the resolution of route comps) starts before an app is mounted. If this is the case, delaying a router may help https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1377#issuecomment-368498552

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks for your idea. I have moved the unhandledrejection listener to before creating the app and router in the main.js like this
`
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App";

window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function (event) {
  console.warn("uncaught (in promise) from main.js " + event.reason);
});

const app = createApp(App);

import { store } from "./store.js";
app.use(store);

import router from "./router";
app.use(router);

app.mount("#app");

`
Still the listener is not fired

Comment: Consider providing a way to reproduce it. This likely means that the error is handled by the framework so it doesn't propagate to unhandledrejection