# catching error event message from firefox

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, throw

I can't find a way to catch the error message under firefox:

```
window.addEventListener("error", handleException, false);

...

function handleException(e) {   
    alert(e);
    return false;
}

...

<script>
throw new Error('sdasd');
</script>
```

This enters very well the `handleException` method however the `e` parameter is an `error event` under firefox **and I don't know how to get the associated message**.
In chrome for instance, I get either the message through `e.message` because after the error bubbles up to not being caught, there's an automatic error fired at window level (See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fz9y8/): the final error is "Uncaught") that contains the original error that I raised manually.

So to have the same behaviour under firefox (if you run the fiddle under firefox you'll see that the message is "undefined") I found a workaround consisting in encapsulating an error raising function to setup a manual "last error" architecture:

```
function err(I_sText) { 
    g_lastManualError = new Error(I_sText);
    throw g_lastManualError; //this variable is global so I can get the message from anywhere
}
```

So instead of doing `throw new Error(..)` I only call `err(..)`. That works, at least for user defined exceptions, which are my biggest concern. In my handler `handleException` I'm consulting the global variable.

Do you know how I could do otherwise? I'm not happy with this solution.

Thank you,
S.

Comment: `e.message` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Apparently Firefox lacks that property.

Comment: @ExplosionPills no it does not, but under chrome it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code a little as a demo:

```
function handleException(e) { 
    console.log(e);
    alert(e);
    return false;
}
window.addEventListener("error", handleException, false);

try {
  throw new Error('sdasd');
}
catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
console.log('after exception 1');
throw new Error('foo');
console.log('after exception 2');
```

Running this code (in Firebug) showed me this:

```
Error: sdasd
[Break On This Error]   

Filtered chrome url chrome://firebug/content/console/commandLineExposed.js

comman...osed.js (line 175)
<System>

after exception 1

"Error: foo `    throw new Error('foo');` @14"
```

If you're trying to catch an error, use `try {...} catch { ...}`.  It looks like you're just binding to an error event, so the exception you're throwing will still propagate up to window and tell the JS engine to halt.  Run this code in Chrome, you'll see that you never see "after exception 2", but you will see "after exception 1".

The purpose of exceptions (created by `throw`) is to stop code execution unless there's code made to handle that particular exception.  You can see an example on the [MDN page for try-catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

**Edit**: it just occurred to me that you might be trying to catch a jQuery error event.  If this is the case, your event binding is correct but you shouldn't be testing it with `throw`

**Edit 2**: I should've noticed this sooner, but you're trying to listen for a DOM error event with `window.addEventListener`.  Error events will not break execution.  Exceptions do.

Replace your code `throw new Error('sdasd');` with this code:

```
var customEvent = new CustomEvent('error')

window.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
```

That should solve your problem.  I used [the MDN page on custom events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Creating_and_triggering_events) as a reference.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Thanks for pointing out the error is not stopped from progagating. This happends under FF only, the `return false` in the error handler does the job in chrome. I added an event cancelation in FF and the error does not bubble anymore. However, I still don't know how to get the error message from the `handleException` method.

Comment: I think you're confusing two things.  There's error *events* like the ones jQuery will fire.  Then there's Javascript *exceptions* which are meant to halt code execution.  They're handled differently--which one are you trying to work with?

Comment: when an unexpected error is thrown, or I throw it voluntarly, I'm today very well catching everything with this method (that's perfect, everything goes through my handler). However, firefox does not give me the event information, being from a custom exception or an error event from the window.

Comment: @Sebas the code in your post is an **error event** handler.  It does not catch exceptions.  Firefox isn't giving you a message because you're throwing an exception, not triggering an error event.  See my edit.

Comment: my event handler also works when `throw` is used (don't ask me why, that's actually a good question). The problem is that the error event catched does not have properties. I tried your suggestion and it indeed raises a CustomEvent and enters the exception handler. But then the problem is the same, filling the `detail` field, it is not provided back in the handler. Thank you so much for your help.