# Is it possible to get notifed when hosted Chromium Embedded has a JavaScript error?

Tags: .net, winforms, chromium, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

Having used the standard WinForms `WebBrowser` control in the past, I was able to get [`OLECMDID_SHOWSCRIPTERROR` notifications](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/261003/en-us) whenever a script error occurs inside the currently loaded page of the hosted web browser control.

Now I'm switching to use [Chromium Embedded](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) (through the [CefSharp .NET wrapper](https://github.com/chillitom/CefSharp)) and look for something similar.

I could think of [injecting some JavaScript code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/951811/107625), but really would love to have a solution that does not require to alter the HTML at all.

**My question:**

Is it somehow possible that Chromium Embedded notifies my application when a JavaScript error occurs in the current loaded page?

*(I'm also [asking this in the CefSharp group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cefsharp/843u54Q_JWI) ant think that this might be independent so asking it here on Stack Overflow, too)*

**Update 1:**

I see that there seems to be an [`OnUncaughtException` function](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs/projects/%28default%29/CefV8ContextHandler.html#OnUncaughtException%28CefRefPtr%3CCefBrowser%3E,CefRefPtr%3CCefFrame%3E,CefRefPtr%3CCefV8Context%3E,CefRefPtr%3CCefV8Exception%3E,CefRefPtr%3CCefV8StackTrace%3E%29) that currently seems to not be implemented by CefSharp. Not sure whether this is about JavaScript errors or CEF errors, though.

Answer (score 6):

Although it does not give you the specificity of explicitly knowing when something is an error, you can bind to the `ConsoleMessage` event. I use this in conjunction with `Log4Net` to keep track of all console messages from Chromium, which includes most javascript errors:

```
var webView = new WebView(startUrl, browserSettings);
webView.ConsoleMessage += (sender, args) =>
                                        {
                                log.Debug(string.Format("Webview {0}({1}): {2}", 
                                                                   args.Source, 
                                                                   args.Line, 
                                                                   args.Message))
                                         };
```

Comment: The ConsoleMessage event isn't raised for errors, at least not all of them. Try hooking window.onerror to pipe the messages to the console first.

Comment: In my Angular app I'm adding an `$httpProvider.interceptors` to log failed calls in a way that `ConsoleMessage` will receive

Comment: What is the ConsoleMessage  event raised for then?