# Can I catch a JavaScript error that my code did not throw?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have some code that I cannot edit that sometimes errors out due to various reason I cannot control.  This can be a failed ajax call (non-jQuery) or simply a function that fails.  Is there any way I can do a generic JS error catch (I do use jQuery) if I do not have access to the code that generates them?

Comment: Does that help you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951791/javascript-global-error-handling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)

```
window.onerror = function() {
    alert("error");
};
```