# When error is returned

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering if its possible to run a function when a specific error is returned in the console. For example Google maps sometimes returns this error.

```
InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lng: not a number
```

What I want to do is send an `alert()` message when this specific error occurs. Is this possible and how would I achieve it?

Comment: nice question im also interessted in, if there is a handler which will be triggered by a displayed error in the console....

Comment: It's better to check the values prior to drawing the map, then you won't receive the error, otherwise, go with a try / catch block

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript global error handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951791/javascript-global-error-handling)

Comment: @JaromandaX I am with you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a try-catch block. see below on this page: [handling a specific error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)

in your case:

```
if (e instanceof InvalidValueError) {
...
```