# How to prevent / catch http error outout in console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

Is there any way to prevent http errors to appear in the console?

E.g. when I try to geo locate the user ip I call

```
$.get( "https://freegeoip.net/json/", function( data ) { 
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

I sometimes get a 503 and cannot catch it before it is displayed to my users in the console.

Try / catch does not seem work here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/951811/4229270

Comment: @sinto How would you catch ajax request returning a server side error???

Comment: try{} catch(e){} should do it.

Comment: @sinto: this did not work for me. do jou have a jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use $.ajax instead of $.get for better customization

Jquery $.get

```
$.get('https://freegeoip.net/json/', function(data){ 
    alert( "Load was performed." );
}).fail(function() {
    alert('woops'); // or your error handling code
});
```

Jquery $.ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://freegeoip.net/json/',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){ 
        alert( "Load was performed." );
    },
    error: function(data) {
         alert('woops!');// or your error handling code
    }
});
```

Comment: try catch does not work here. there is still a console error.

Comment: I didn't suggest you to use try catch....

well could please let me know what error you are getting in console

Comment: You get the "woops" alert plus the regular http error in the console. just copy it to a JSFiddle with jquery. there you can see.