# How to Handle JavaScript exceptions globally in a single method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to control whole JavaScript application exceptions through a common method written but can't get any exact solution for the problem. I tried below code but sometimes it not worked

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            window.onerror = function () {
               alert("An error occurred.");
            }

      </script>
```

The same can be achieved in angular using below method :

```
$provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', function ($delegate) {
        return function (exception, cause) {
            $delegate(exception, cause);
            var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);
            var $http = initInjector.get('$http');

            $http({
              method: 'POST',
              url: '/api/common/send_email',
              data: {message: new Date() +': '+ exception.stack},
              headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
              }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {

              }, function errorCallback(response) {

              });
        };
    });
```

Can anyone please help me with a similar method in pure JavaScript or Jquery to handle complete application exceptions through a single method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript global error handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951791/javascript-global-error-handling)

Comment: Can you give us an example of situation where the provided code did not work and how would you have expected it to work?

Answer (score 0):

just don't use comments, should be like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onerror = function myErrHandler(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
        alert("Error: " + errorMsg);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```