# How to continue execution after Uncaught DOMException?

Tags: javascript

I'm performing a long-running task, and somewhere in the middle, it's possible that this exception can be thrown:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://localhost:8000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

The problem is, once this exception is thrown, my long-running, unrelated task is broken up and does not complete successfully. Something about this DOMException messes everything up.

I've tried using `window.onerror` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10556743/458960), but all this does is allow me to inspect the error, not prevent it from breaking the application.

Note that I can't use regular try/catch blocks since this iframe is being loaded in HTML.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using a try...catch block?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_try_catch.asp

Comment: See update. Can't use regular try/catch blocks since this iframe is being loaded in HTML.

Comment: Can you explain more about your "unrelated task". As far as I know, this security exception shouldn't affect any of your other code.

Comment: Well, let's say I'm importing an array of 10,000 URLs, and somewhere in the middle, if I encounter a specific URL (let's say at index 2,000), I'll load that into the iframe (via JS/Angular). If that exception occurs, the remaining 8,000 URLs are not imported, because the import task is broken up.

Comment: Can you modify the code ran in the iframe?

Comment: @RainingChain not sure what you mean?

Comment: @Snowman Instead of adding a try and catch on the embedder of the iframe, modify the iframe code itself and add a try and catch.

Comment: The iframe code itself is not loaded since it violates the same-origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you catching the exception and handling it gracefully by surrounding it in a try-catch statement?

https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: Can't use regular try/catch blocks since this iframe is being loaded in HTML.