# Javascript: Catch all OnError s

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I saw a Code to make A default image To be shown when there is a 404 error when loading a image.

Something Like this:

```
<img src="img/article_1744408190.jpg" onerror="this.src = 'ImgAlt.jpg'">
```

But It has to call `onerror` function from each each Image. But how can I implement A method to catch all the onerror triggers by Javascript(or JQuery) and individually set the image SRC to `default.jpg`.Posting A sample Code will be useful

Comment: Yeah! Posting a sample code will be useful for us too! How have you tried solving the problem other than adding the `onerror` property on all images manually?

Comment: More on how the `alt` attribute is meant to be used: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#alt

Comment: The only way I know how to do this is with [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers)s and adding a `fetch` event listener. It is _much_ simpler to add `onerror` handlers in a build step then to actually do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the error event listener on `window` ([**global error handling**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951791/6647153)) and check if he target is an image, if so change its `src`:

```
window.addEventListener("error", function(e) {              // when an error happens
    if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "img") {          // if the target is an image
        e.target.src = "default.jpg";                       // then change its src to whatever you want
    }
}, true);
```

```js
window.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
    if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "img") {
        e.target.src = "http://via.placeholder.com/200/ff0000/000000?text=404";
    }
}, true);
```

```html
<img src="http://example.com/nonExistingImage.jpg">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200/00ff00/000000?text=OK">
```

Comment: Does the global error handler actually fire for `img` tags?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes

Comment: Then can you please explain what I missed in my fiddle? It looks like this solution does not work.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I've added a working example to the answer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Looks like the `alert` was the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/mvxke2en/3/

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - Is this specified and/or documented anywhere? Does it work in mobile browsers? (BTW, that via.placeholder.com thing is really cool!)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the _alert_ was the problem :O That sounds like a bug to me. Will ping about it in the #whatwg room to see what they have to say.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Not sure if MDN count as "documented anywhere", but the second bullet point [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) seems to say just that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it does - the `error` event [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#onerroreventhandler) - I recall it specified in the media element loading page but I can't find it.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - :-) A lot of people think MDN is "official documentation," but it isn't, you're right to couch things a bit because it isn't official (just community-edited and very good). It usually links to sources, but the link in this case doesn't seem to say that it works im the way above. Frustrating. :-)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - I know about the global error handler, I just meant the aspects of it that the above relies on -- that it fires for broken images, will have a target that is the element that failed, etc.

Comment: Thanks Guys. Work Like A charm :)

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to hook the `error` event, then go back and check the images to see if any of them have *already* errored (before you hooked the event) to handle them. Along these lines:

```
var defaultImage = "ImgAlt.jpg";
$("img").one("error", function() {
    this.src = defaultImage;
}).each(function() {
    if (this.complete && !this.naturalWidth) {
        this.src = defaultImage;
        $(this).off("error");
    }
});
```

`complete` will be `true` when the image is broken. `naturalWidth` will be the natural width of the image, and either `0` or `undefined` if it's broken. Sadly that latter check is just about the only way to know the image is broken, since [they lack](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#htmlimageelement) any (blindingly-obviously-needed) error indicator after the event. (`naturalWidth` [is supported by all modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=img-naturalwidth-naturalheight) and also IE9-IE11; it is not supported by the truly-obsolete IE8.)

---

Note the assumption that none of the images you want to load is actually zero-width. Seemed like a safe assumption. :-)

Comment: You probably want to add a delegating handler instead to deal with images added dynamically - otherwise this is pretty simple and works.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - `error` doesn't bubble, even though the specification says it's supposed to. :-) There's a warning about that in the jQuery docs.

Comment: Note the assumption that none of the images you want to load is actually zero-width - this is not safe assumption as most pixel codes are using `img` tag to load pixel

Comment: @Vivek - Those are 1 pixel wide, though, not 0, surely? Can you even create a 0-width image in any of the standard formats?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder pixels are not actual images, they are just api calls (for ex `<img src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=<PIXEL_ID>&amp;noscript=1" height="0" width="0" style="display:none"/>`, in this case if call fails then it will fire up `error` event and `defaultImage` will load up, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Vivek - And yet, the response must define an image, and again, can you even define a zero-width image in any of the standard formats? But this is all a pointless digression anyway; if the OP is doing what they're doing, obviously they're not using Facebook pixels. The entire concern here is completely irrelevant.