# Error: uncaught exception: compile error:

Tags: javascript, canvas

i used glfx.js to add some effects on canvas. I created a button that changes the canvas and sometimes i get the error "Error: uncaught exception: compile error:". I got more details thanks to [JavaScript global error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951791/javascript-global-error-handling/10556743#10556743).

I assigned the window.onerror event to an event handler and i got :

Error: uncaught exception: compile error: 
url: 
line: 0

error: compile error:

How can i resolve that error ?

code :

```
function createContrastCanvas( imgEffect, canvasSent, p, A, x ) {
        $( ".loaderImgEffects" ).fadeIn();
        var base64 = canvasSent.toDataURL( "image/jpeg" );
        var image = new Image();
        image.setAttribute( "id", "contrast_image");

        image.addEventListener( "load", function() {
            console.log(2);
            document.body.appendChild( image );
                try {
                    var canvas = fx.canvas();
                    canvas.setAttribute( "id", "dialog_canvas" );
                    console.log(3);
                } catch (e) {
                    alert(e);
                    return;
                }

                // convert the image to a texture
                var contrastImage = document.getElementById( 'contrast_image' );
                var texture = canvas.texture( contrastImage );
                console.log( 4 );


                switch( imgEffect ) {
                    case "contrast":
                    console.log(5);
                        canvas.draw(texture).brightnessContrast(0.1, 0.24).update();
                        //contrastBase64[0] = canvas.toDataURL( "image/jpeg" ); 
                        contrastBase64[0] = image;
                    break;

                    case "hue":
                    console.log(5);
                        canvas.draw(texture).hueSaturation( 0, 0.39 ).update();
                        //hueBase64[0] = canvas.toDataURL( "image/jpeg" );                         
                        hueBase64[0] = image;              
                    break;

                    /*case "denoise":
                        canvas.draw(texture).unsharpMask(20, 0.45).update();
                    break;*/
                }

                    console.log(6);
                // replace the image with the canvas
                $( "#dialog_canvas" ).parent().html( canvas );

                $( ".loaderImgEffects" ).fadeOut();
                //activeAllEvents( canvas, p, A, x );
                //document.getElementById( "dialog_canvas" ).parentNode.removeChild( contrastImage );
        } )
        image.src = base64;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: thanks for helping, i put code at the top

Comment: Sorry but with that code I can not reproduce you issue, read about https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve