# Collect errors from Chrome extension and send report

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is possible to send an error report from my Chrome Extension to my server?
or at least log somewhere in local to request that info to the user?

**EDIT**
I mean the errors logged by the Chrome extension (when we are in developer mode). That is: errors not catched by my code

Comment: Why not? What seems to be a problem? Simply use whatever method any web page does. Like AJAX or sendBeacon.

Comment: because the extension stops working when an error occurs, javascript in general have that problem, but in developer mode I can see a log of errors

Comment: @wOxxOm is a generic question, I mean any non catched error in our code

Comment: Then use a generic listener for 'error' event on `window`. There's no special API for extensions.

Comment: Perfect, actually I found is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951791/javascript-global-error-handling

Answer (score 2):

You can use any error reporting tool as usual.
https://sentry.io
https://www.bugsnag.com/