# detect all JS errors, using JS

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I know this has probably been asked before, but I can't find where:

I know you can detect JS errors using extensions in stuff, but is there any way to detect ALL errors using JavaScript and display an alert whenever there is one?

Comment: Wrap everything in `try ... catch`

Comment: @argo49 i need a way to detect it from the script, not the console

Comment: Nope, javascript execution generally halts on errors. You could wrap everything in try / catch, but it would probably be better to not write code with errors in it, or at least just use the console to fix them.

Comment: @Barmar would that work? Just put ALL script in a try/catch?

Comment: It will work for everything except syntax errors, since those are detected before anything runs.

Comment: @adeneo well this error is only happening on mobile, and my friend is testing it for me and for some reason something isn't working right...so i need this

Comment: It won't work for callback functions, though, since they're called outside the dynamic scope of the `try`.

Comment: Mobile testing is available at BrowserStack. I don't know much about the debugging environment for them, though.

Comment: i don't want to pay for it :)

Comment: See this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/12664434/362536  I tried a bunch of stuff that didn't work in my situation, but most of those will probably work in yours.

Comment: will just using `window.onerror` work?

Comment: @Barmer how do you wrap 3rd party scripts which you cannot edit in try/catch ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the browser define the `window.onerror` function. In node attached to the `uncaughtException` event with `process.on()`.

This should **ONLY** be used if your need to trap all errors, such as in a spec runner or console.log/ debugging implementation. Otherwise, you will find yourself in a world of hurt trying to track down strange behavior. Like several have suggested, in normal day to day code a `try / catch` block is the proper and best way to handle errors/exceptions.

For reference in the former case, see [this (about window.error in browsers)](http://www.w3.org/wiki/DOM/window.onerror) and [this (about uncaughtException in node)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4214095/227176). Examples:

#### Browser

```
window.onerror = function(error) {
  // do something clever here
  console.log(error);
};
```

#### Node.js

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(error) {
  // do something clever here
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: How do you try / catch script errors from 3rd party scripts, which you cannot edit?

Comment: If a 3rd party script crashes then there is a bug in *their* script and the 3rd party needs to informed so they can fix it. Maybe consider an alternative script or wrap your interface to their script with your own code that knows how to handle errors. For sync calls into a 3rd party lib wrap the call in a try/catch. For async 3rd party libs wrap the calls in a Promise constructor.

Comment: nice, but alert is not built-in function in nodejs, its an extra package... its better u update it to console.log

Answer (score 0):

**For JS in Browser**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script>
        var lastErr;
        function errHand(e) {
            lastErr = e;
            switch (e.target.nodeName) {
                case 'SCRIPT':
                    alert('script not found: ' + e.srcElement.src);
                    break;
                case 'LINK':
                    alert('css not found: ' + e.srcElement.href);
            }
            return false;
        }
        window.onerror = function (msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) {
            alert(msg + ' - ' + url + ' - ' + lineNo + ' - ' + columnNo);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <script src="http://22.com/k.js" onerror="errHand(event)"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://22.com/k.css" onerror="errHand(event)" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        not_exist_function();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

- This works for attached js files trace errors just in *same origin host* environment
- For Request error handeling like *Ajax/WebSocket* its better use their Bulit-In functions
- Console functions override not work for reading auto generated browser error logs *at this time* with latest browser updates

**For NodeJS**

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.error('uncaughtException:\n' + err.stack + '\n');
})
```

***Use Both of them in the TOP of your codes***