# How can i catch all the javascript console warnings and perform actions based on different warnings

Tags: javascript, android-webview, android-jsinterface

I have an html content which when loaded to the webview throws some warnings in console. Is there any way to capture and compare these warnings to perform specific actions for specific warning in javascript.

Comment: In Javascript, you can only catch errors, not warnings. Warnings are **Browser based** only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [detect all JS errors, using JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534457/detect-all-js-errors-using-js)

Comment: The scenario is as follows, I have an html content for which the associated fonts are not proper hence when i load the content in the webview it throws some warnings saying invalid version tag. Is there any way where i can get to know that the fonts are not valid so that i can add some default style over the page.

Answer (score 0):

Since console warning do not originate from Javascript itself, but from the **browser**, Javascript does not interface catching warnings, only errors.

Comment: the scenario is as follows, I have an html content for which the associated fonts are not proper hence when i load the content in the webview it throws some warnings saying invalid version tag. Is there any way where i can get to know that the fonts are not valid so that i can add some default style over the page. Else is there any way we can check the font files for valid fonts or not.

Comment: what is the exact warning text?

Comment: Failed to decode downloaded font: file:///storage/emulated/0/book/9789531421508/OEBPS/font/Archer-Book.otf
HYGGE-6.xhtml:1 OTS parsing error: invalid version tag