# WebView2 / CoreWebView2 - Detecting if a javascript error happens

Tags: javascript, webview2

I have written a web-crawler to test a pre-release website for errors and issues (i.e. missing content type, timeouts, exceptions, redirects).

This morning a colleague asked me to include a check if there was any javascript error on the page...

A pure javascript solution is unlikely -- i.e. [detect all JS errors, using JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534457/detect-all-js-errors-using-js)

What I appear to want to be able to do is capture the javascript console text, ideally via CoreWebView2

Answer (score 0):

If the page logs each exception into an array,

Errors=[]
window.onerror = function (msg, url, line) {
Errors.push("Caught[via window.onerror]: '" + msg + "' from " + url + ":" + line);
return true;
};

Then you can just query the Errors and see both the count and the nature of the errors.

You can also push errors from try catch